# Is there a way to show statistic info?

Tags: 3d-view, vertices, faces

Is there a way to get Statistic info in Blender? Or heads up display? Like when I select a group of vertices, I need a way to know how many vertices are selected and How many polygons "or triangles my scene has.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

For Blender 2.79 and older check the header of the *Info Window*, above the *3D View* to the right by default on the factory screen layout.

[image: 2.79 Statistics]

For Blender 2.8* series check the status bar running along the bottom of every main window towards the right.

[image]

For 2.9 series this has been moved into each independent viewport, so it can display relevant statistics for each separate 3D View depending on what is shown/selected in them. You can toggle it on or off from the *Overlays Popover* in the 3D View header.

[image]

There are statistics about the scene's total count of vertices, faces and triangles, in addition to your current selection of objects.

If you enter *Edit Mode*, it will switch to showing statistics about currently selected objects.

Global scene statistics (not dependent on viewport states) can be found on the status bar, in addition to system stats, like available memory and GPU VRAM.

[image]

If you need to see them at the bottom right of the screen you can enable the information using Edit > Preferences > Interface > Editors > Status Bar, and enable the information you want to view as part of the *Status Bar*.

You can also just right click on them and pick the desired options.

[image]

Comment: There's no way to have statistics about the selected object? I am working on an object and trying to optimize it, can't see its exact stats, apparently...

Comment: Isolate the current object

Comment: Is this accessible via python? For instance ```Triangles``` for scene?

Answer (score 10):

2.9 still has it where 2.8 did.

Right click the bottom bar and add scene statistics.

Comment: Same with Blender 3.2.0 - at the very bottom of the Blender window (you'll see "Select", "Rotate View", etc). Right click, check "Scene statistics"

Comment: Same on Blender 3.6.2