# How to make Display fonts bigger

Tags: interface

Is there any way I can make "Scene Statistics' A bit bigger than its original size? and also I want to make it white color font so that I can read it easily, how can I change the color into white as well.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: if it ever helps, you can show the statistics on the top left, enable the option in the Viewport Overlays: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/49654/is-there-a-way-to-show-statistic-info

Comment: :O Thank you MoonBoots.

Comment: For future reference you can change the status bar font colour via Edit > Preferences > Themes > Status Bar > Theme Space > Header Text (Phew!...), but not the font size. :^)

Comment: @JohnEason Thank you so much.

Comment: @RussianBlue No problem. It took a while to find! I'll add it as an answer with an image of where to change the setting. The status bar seems to be the only part of Blender where you can't change the font size. Other panels can be changed by dragging with Ctrl-MMB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Status Bar text Colour can be changed under Edit > Preferences in Blender as shown below where I'm changing it from grey to full white. The font size can't be changed as far as I can see.

[image]